Spark On-Prem EWS - CDATA JDBC read returning a null body and no attachment list
I am trying to receive the body and attachments IDs of an email from an EWS On-Prem server using the CDATA JDBC driver, however, it is always coming back null. The Subject line, ItemId, dates, and involved email addresses all come back correctly. CDATA documentation states that I should be seeing content through a conventional query. The Spark version is 3.0.0 and the scala version is 2.12.12. Is there a permission the admin account is missing that allows it to see an email body specifically or is this a known problem?
var query = "select Body, UniqueBody, UniqueBodyType, Attachments, HasAttachments FROM Inbox"

val df = spark.sqlContext.read.format("jdbc")
          .option("url", url)
          .option("query", query)
          .option(DRIVER, CDATA_EXCHANGE_DRIVER)
          .load()


